# How to extract different values/elements of matrix or array without repeating?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

I have a vector/ or it could be array :

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
```

I want to extract existing  different values/elements from this vector without repeating:

```
1,2,3,4,5
B= [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can I extract it ?

I would appreciate for any help please

Comment: `B = unique(A)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
y = unique(A)
```

`B = unique(A)` returns the same values as in a but with no repetitions. The resulting vector is sorted in ascending order. `A` can be a cell array of strings.

`B = unique(A,'stable')` does the same as above, but without sorting.

`B = unique(A,'rows') returns the unique rows of`A`.

`[B,i,j] = unique(...)` also returns index vectors `i` and `j` such that `B = A(i)` and `A = B(j)` (or `B = A(i,:)` and `A = B(j,:)`).

---

Reference: http://cens.ioc.ee/local/man/matlab/techdoc/ref/unique.html

Documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html

Comment: let me know if that helps @Agata Krasoń

Comment: Doesn't need to unique, I didn't notice your comment

Comment: I suggest you use a reference to the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

The answers below are correct but if the user does not want to sort the data, you can use `unique` with the parameter `stable`

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
B = unique(A,'stable')
```